# How do I use the Advanced filter in excel to exclude filtered data instead of include it

Tags: excel, filtering

I have a large data set from which I need to filter out all rows containing key words from another large data set I have set up. I know how to use the advanced filters function in excel but it will only remove the data without the key words instead of removing the data with the key words.

I only have the information on the key words that the rows must not include as its opposite(key word it can include) is far to large for use with this function.

Please help!

Comment: Are you doing this manually, or with VBA? Why not just go through the list and manually select the data you want to not include? More specifics, please.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a list of 9 colors, and I want to filter out every value that isn't "Pink" or "Yellow". In order to filter out that exact list, I have to create an array based on my requirements, then filter on that array. So in this example, we loop through all the values and if they're not pink or yellow, we add them to the array - then we filter on it:

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long

j = 0

For i = 2 To 10
    If Range("A" & i).Value <> "Pink" And Range("A" & i).Value <> "Yellow" Then
        If j = 0 Then
            ReDim arr(0 To 0)
            arr(j) = Range("A" & i).Value
            j = j + 1
        Else
            j = j + 1
            ReDim Preserve arr(0 To j)
            arr(j) = Range("A" & i).Value
        End If
    End If
Next i

Range("$A$1:$A$10").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=arr, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

Example:

[image: img1]